# Multiple if conditions in Java

Tags: android, if-statement, multiple-instances

I am wondering how to write multiple conditions in Java.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= pqrst; i++) {
    P = P + "{" + Pxcoor[i] + "," + Pycoor[i] + "} ; ";
    Q = Q + "{" + Qxcoor[i] + "," + Qycoor[i] + "} ; ";
    R1 = R1 + "{" + Rxcoor[i] + "," + Rycoor[i] + "} ; ";
    S = S + "{" + Sxcoor[i] + "," + Sycoor[i] + "} ; ";
    T = T + "{" + Txcoor[i] + "," + Tycoor[i] + "} ; ";


    if (i >= 2) {
        rrdistance += (((Rxcoor[i] - Rxcoor[i - 1]) / FINALBOXWIDTH(bitmap_Source)) * 0.04);//durations in seconds
        printerval += (((Rxcoor[i] - Pxcoor[i]) / FINALBOXWIDTH(bitmap_Source)) * 0.04);
        qsdistance += (((Sxcoor[i] - Qxcoor[i]) / FINALBOXWIDTH(bitmap_Source)) * 0.04);
        heartrate += (1500 / (rrdistance / 0.04)); 

    //amplitude in mV
        pamp = (( (trial[1] - Pycoor[i]) / (double)FINALBOXWIDTH(bitmap_Source))  * 0.1);
        qamp = (( (Qycoor[i] - trial[i]) / (double)FINALBOXWIDTH(bitmap_Source)) *0.1);
        ramp = (( (trial[1] - Rycoor[i]) / (double)FINALBOXWIDTH(bitmap_Source)) *0.1);
        samp = (( (Sycoor[i] - trial[i]) / (double)FINALBOXWIDTH(bitmap_Source)) *0.1);
        tamp = (( (trial[1] - Tycoor[i]) / (double)FINALBOXWIDTH(bitmap_Source)) *0.1);


                        }
                    }
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
rrdistance = rrdistance / (pqrst - 1);
RRdistance = RRdistance + " " + rrdistance + " " + "seconds";
PRinterval = PRinterval + " " + printerval + " " + "seconds";
QSdistance = QSdistance + " " + qsdistance + " " + "seconds";
HeartRate = HeartRate + " " + heartrate + " " + "bpm";

Pamp = Pamp + " " + df.format(pamp) + " " + "mV";
Qamp = Qamp + " " + df.format(qamp) + " " + "mV";
Ramp = Ramp + " " + df.format(ramp) + " " + "mV";
Samp = Samp + " " + df.format(samp) + " " + "mV";
Tamp = Tamp + " " + df.format(tamp) + " " + "mV";

coordinate.setText("Peak coordinates:" + "\n" + P + "\n" + Q + "\n" + R1 + "\n" + S
+ "\n" + T + "\n" + RRdistance + "\n" + PRinterval + "\n" + QSdistance + "\n"
+ HeartRate + " "+ "\n" + "Amplitude of peaks:" + "\n" + Pamp + ";"  + " " + Qamp + ";"     + " "  + Ramp + ";" + " "  + Samp + ";" + " "  + Tamp + ";");
```

I am going to use heartrate, pamp, printerval, and qsdistance. How do I write all these conditions in one if statement?

```
if (60 <= heartrate <= 100) && (0 <= pamp <= 0.25) && (0.12 <= printerval <= 0.20) && (0.04 <= qsdistance < 0.12)
```

If all these conditions are satisfied then it will display NORMAL. Else, ABNORMAL.

I tried putting all these in one if statement but it displays an error. I hope you help me figure out how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: how did you put all these?? Show the code...

Answer (score 2):

```
if (60 <= heartrate <= 100)
```

wont work because you compare a boolean to 100  The `60 <= hearrate` returns True or False., use :

```
if (heartrate >=60 && heartrate <=100)
```

like so

```
if ((heartrate >= 60 && heartrate <= 100) && (pamp >= 0 && pamp <= 0.25) && (printerval >= 0.12  &&printerval <= 0.20) && (qdistance >= 0.04 && qsdistance < 0.12)){
}
```

Comment: How do I put ALL the conditions above in one if statement? The goal is if all those conditions are met, it is NORMAL. Else, it is not.

Comment: So OP was very close but you've to embrace the full boolean expression with `()` instead if every single value with `&&` between.

Comment: Just pointing out that "in between" statement is the biggest issue there. , then just wrap every condition with ()

Answer (score 2):

It would be like this:

```
 if ((heartrate >= 60) && (heartrate <= 100) && (pamp >=0) && (pamp <= 0.25) && (printerval >= 0.12) && (printerval <= 0.20) && (qsdistance >= 0.04) && (qsdistance < 0.12))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it if it helps:

```
if ((60 <= heartrate) && (heartrate <= 100) && (0 <= pamp) && (pamp <= 0.25) && (0.12 <= printerval) 
&& (printerval <= 0.20) && (0.04 <= qsdistance) && (qsdistance < 0.12)) {

  //Display NORMAL Here(use textview or Log whatever you want)
 } else {
 //Abnormal
}
```

Comment: It says "syntax error on token &&, throw expected". @Android Killer

Comment: Missing `(`! Try `if (( ...`

Comment: How do I display the "NORMAL" inside if() { } ? @yoshi

Comment: Thank you. But how do I display that in a textView? And after which line should I put it? I tried putting it in a textView after the coordinate.setText.. and it force closes. @Android Killer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?

```
if ((60 <= heartrate && heartrate <= 100) && (0 <= pamp && pamp <= 0.25) && (0.12 <= printerval && printerval <= 0.20) && (0.04 <= qsdistance && qsdistance < 0.12))
```

Comment: The whole boolean expression which shall be evaluated by `if` has to be put in `( )`

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually a little bit scared to see three answer not following Java syntax for an `if`statement so let's clarify.

```
if( [boolean expresison] ){
  [then block]
}
```

A boolean expression can be a simple test like `5 > b`, `someArray.isEmpty()` or just `true`. An addition you can use logical operators like AND `&&`, OR `||` or NOT `!` to chain multiple booleans and evaluate it to one expression. E.g.

```
if( foo && bar || !quix){
  return true;
}
```

You se the ecnlosing `()` stay **untouched**!

[If-then statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((heartrate >=60 && heartrate <=100) && 
                (pamp >= 0 && pamp <= 0.25) && 
                (printerval >= 0.12 && printerval <= 0.20) &&
                (qsdistance >= 0.04 && qsdistance <= 0.04)) {
            System.out.println("NORMAL");

        } else { System.out.println("ABNORMAL"); }
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I display that in a textView? And after which line should I put it? @Sarath Kumar Sivan

Comment: replace the sysout inside the if with txtView.setText("NORMAL"); and else block with txtView.setText("ABNORMAL");

Comment: Is this correct? if ((60 <= heartrate && heartrate <= 100) && (0 <= pamp && pamp <= 0.25) && 
        (0.12 <= printerval && printerval <= 0.20) && (0.04 <= qsdistance && qsdistance < 0.12))
      {
       result.setText("Result is NORMAL!");
      }
      else 
      {
       result.setText("Result is ABNORMAL!");
      }

Comment: After which line should I put it? It force closes. @Sarath Kumar Sivan

Comment: It is correct only but I don't understand why you are comparing the value like this: (60 <= heartrate && heartrate <= 100). If you would like to check the value of heartrate is in between 60 and 100, you must use (heartrate >=60 && heartrate <=100).

Comment: OK, I have changed it. Where should I put the whole if statement? @Sarath Kumar Siwan